# How to parse 18-digit sqlite timestamp

Tags: sqlite

The sqlite timestamp here is 18 digits, but how can one know its specific date. 132079170460000000 should correspond to July 2019, but this year cannot be obtained regardless of interpretation or other conversions. I want to get time like 2019-07-30 13:23:40.

This is sqllite timestamp, but product specific model does not know,only know that this timestamp is 18-digit just like these:
    132079170420000000
    132079218060000000

Comment: You need to tell us what this 18 digit number actually represents?

Comment: I think you're confusing bits and digits. Those aren't 18 bit numbers...

Comment: sqlite does not have any native timestamp type.  It supports certain [date/time functions](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html), but the actual storage will either be a string value or for julian dates, a numeric value... but not 18 digits.

Comment: such as 132089746940000000 means "2019-07-31 13:42:31"，but i don't know how to convert

Comment: That same date and time in Unix Epoch Time (milliseconds) is 1564580551000.  The sqlite `julianday()` function returns 2458696.07119213.  The numbers you have are apparently for a different epoch or unknown algorithm.

Comment: See this [Wikipedia article on computing epochs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epoch_(computing)).  Perhaps it fits into one of the listed epochs, and/or was produced by one of the listed languages/platforms.  Otherwise you did not give enough information about where the data came from.

Answer (score 0):

If 132089746940000000 is equivalent to "2019-07-31 13:42:31" as mentioned in the comments, then try this:

```
SELECT datetime(  DateColumnWith18Digits / 1.0E11 + 1137798.60179213 )
FROM SomeTable
```

If the example you shared was just a random value, this technique might still work, but you'll need to find the offset factor.  The conversion assumes that the 18-digit value is the number of milliseconds since some epoch.  I simply assumed that one of the comments contained a valid equivalence and found the offset to match the Julian date value.

The reverse encoding would be like

```
SELECT (julianday('2019-07-31 13:42:31') - 1137798.60179213) * 1E11
```